# Is there a way to grant access to a table without creating security privileges?

Tags: axapta, dynamics-ax-2012, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

I have a custom temporary table that is used for a simple custom dialog form.  Users receive an error:
 `You are not authorized to access table ‘TmpAddressEntryPrompt’ (TmpAddressEntryPrompt). Contact your system administrator.`

I can resolve it if I create a privilege and add the table under `Permissions` or if I instead call the form with a custom menu item, and add that menu item to a privilege.  This is extra overhead that I don't want to add for a temporary table.  I've also discovered `AllowCheck = No` on the form datasource, but this just checks after the form is open, so it still doesn't have access.

**Is there a way to just make the temporary table unrestricted for all??**

I call the form like this:

```
args = new Args();
args.name(formStr(AddressEntryPrompt));
args.record(prompt);

promptForm = classFactory.formRunClass(args);
promptForm.init();
promptForm.run();
promptForm.wait(true);

if (promptForm.closedOk())
{
    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The right way is to add the *TmpAddressEntryPrompt* table to your form *AddressEntryPrompt* DataSources (with AllowCreate/AllowEdit).

Little less recommended way is to add this table to the form [Permissions - Tables](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg879980.aspx) (and set `Manual` to *ManagedMy*).

Comment: I do have the table added to the form DataSources. It automatically adds the table to the permissions on the from as well. It seems like one has to still explicitly grant permission to the table. Have you tried it with another restricted user?

Comment: User must have access to the form via Privilege (prefferd by MenuItem). This is by desing and should not be treated as overhead.